# MemeryError installing numpy on Ubuntu 16.04 on Digital Ocean

Tags: numpy, ubuntu-16.04, digital-ocean

I have a python application that uses numpy running on my digital Ocean droplet. I am trying to pip install numpy into my virtual environment and each time i am getting an error like this:

```
Collecting numpy
  Downloading numpy-1.13.1-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (16.6MB)
    99% |████████████████████████████████| 16.6MB 40.5MB/s eta 
    0:00:01Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 209, in 
    main
status = self.run(options, args)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 328, 
  in run
wb.build(autobuilding=True)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 748, in build
   self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 360, in 
prepare_files
 ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 577, in 
   _prepare_file
    session=self.session, hashes=hashes)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 810, in 
  unpack_url
   hashes=hashes
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 649, in 
 unpack_http_url
  hashes)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 871, in 
 _download_http_url
    _download_url(resp, link, content_file, hashes)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 595, in 
  _download_url
     hashes.check_against_chunks(downloaded_chunks)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/utils/hashes.py", line 46, in 
    check_against_chunks
for chunk in chunks:
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 563, in 
 written_chunks
    for chunk in chunks:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/utils/ui.py", line 139, in iter
    for x in it:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 552, in 
resp_read
    decode_content=False):
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.13.1-py2.py3-none-
 any.whl/urllib3/response.py", line 344, in stream
    data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.13.1-py2.py3-none-
any.whl/urllib3/response.py", line 301, in read
    data = self._fp.read(amt)
 File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.11.5-py2.py3-none-
any.whl/cachecontrol/filewrapper.py", line 54, in read
     self.__callback(self.__buf.getvalue())
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.11.5-py2.py3-none-
any.whl/cachecontrol/controller.py", line 224, in cache_response
   self.serializer.dumps(request, response, body=body),
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.11.5-py2.py3-none-
any.whl/cachecontrol/serialize.py", line 81, in dumps
    ).encode("utf8"),
 MemoryError
```

Any who is able lto help me figure out how to solve this problem i have tried installing numpy from outside the virtual-env but it is still refusing to download and install.

Comment: What kind of DO droplet is this? Your droplet might simply have insufficient memory for installing NumPy.

Comment: i have the 512mb ram and 20 gig ssd